# git lfs: wildcard in path works not in git alias

Tags: git, alias, git-lfs

on a windows system, I want to lock all files with a Extension in a specific folder.

These commands work as expected:

```
git lfs lock $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/lockdata/*.txt
git lfs unlock $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/lockdata/*.txt
git add $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/lockdata/*.txt"
```

Now i define aliases:

```
git config --local alias.libsadd      "add $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/lockdata/*.txt"
git config --local alias.libslock     "lfs lock $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/lockdata/*.txt"
git config --local alias.libsunlock   "lfs unlock $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/lockdata/*.txt"
```

Then the .git/config file holds:

```
[alias]
    libslock = lfs lock E:/TEMP/test_lfs/lockdata/*.txt
    libsunlock = lfs unlock E:/TEMP/test_lfs/lockdata/*.txt
    test = add E:/TEMP/test_lfs/lockdata/*.log
```

"git libsadd" works as expected. "git libslock" does not:

```
$ git libslock
lfs: unable to canonicalize path "E:/TEMP/test_lfs/lockdata/*.txt": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Executing directly in git bash works as expected

```
$ git lfs lock E:/TEMP/test_lfs/lockdata/*.txt
Locked lockdata/aaa.txt
Locked lockdata/bbb.txt
```

Executing in commandline does something else (locking a nonexisting "*.txt" file), so a batch file is no workaround

Any ideas where the different behaviour in the alias comes from (and how to fix)?

Comment: `git config --local alias.libsadd      "add $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/lockdata ..."` doing that in a shell runs `git rev-parse` at that time and substitutes the results. Just add an `echo` to the beginning of the commandline (`echo git config ...`) to observe the behaviour. Try using single quotes instead.

Comment: Oh, actually, no. Rather, it inserts a literal `*` into the alias, which `git` doesn't resolve later on. Expanding `*` is done by the shell, usually.

Comment: Windows doesn't do any wildcard expansion and leaves that all to the receiving application. Bash and other Linux shells expand prior to called the requested executable.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds as if there is no hope for getting this to work as I wanted.